# Margin on the chart in NVD3

Tags: html, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

Does anyone know how to put a margin at the top of the chart? I don't know if it's possible or a bug.

I already tried to modify the `.margin({top: x, right: x, bottom: x, left: x})` but this is not the margin that I'm looking for. Setting the `chart.yDomain()` isn't good because I want the chart to rescale.

[image]

**EDIT**

My interest is that the **linewithfocuschart** **rescale**, not just force the domain.

Comment: Could you put your code up on a fiddle so its easy for people to give you help.

Comment: In the example of the site itself happens: http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/lineWithFocusChart.html

Comment: The reason why the top point is clipped is that the yAxis scale's domain is calculated from your data. If you want a margin, you need to set the yAsix scales's domain explicitly, even though you don't want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be when the tooltip appears at the highest point in the chart. Maybe a bug, not really sure.

But here's one way of doing it, might not be the best way:

```
chart.forceY([0,160]);
```

By looking at your chart I'm assuming that 140 is the highest value in you chart. So I'm forcing the `Y axis` on the chart to show values between 0-160.

### Update

Earlier I suggested the use of `chart.forceY([0,160]);` as a work around to adding margin to the chart top so the tooltips are clearly visible with the highest points. Although this approach only makes changes to the main chart and *not the focus chart*.

After some further investigation, I found out that you could use the following to rescale the chart and the focus:

```
chart.lines.forceY([0, yMax])
chart.lines2.forceY([0, yMax])
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/mmz1b3da/) of using with a NVD3 lineWithFocusChart(). I have also got the `yMax`dynamically in `line 15` of my code.

Comment: But I`m using the linewithfocuschart, if I force the Y the rescale wont work.

Comment: @RaphaelSampaio, I've updated my answer with a working example of using `forceY` with a **lineWithFocusChart**

Comment: When you force the domain, the focus doesn't rescale [example](http://imgur.com/7kFYNrm), that's the problem.

Comment: @RaphaelSampaio I've updated my answer to reflect the changes to the chart and the focus. Hopefully that's what you are looking for.